# Amplify/Cognito SignInWithRedirect Facebook Login Error

Tags: facebook, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify for my website and using `aws-amplify/auth`'s `signInWithRedirect` to signin to my website with Facebook like so.

```
  const onClickFacebookSignIn = React.useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await signInWithRedirect({provider: 'Facebook'})
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error)
    }
  }, [])
```

Signing up and signing in is no problem until I change my facebook account's email address from Facebook's Account Center (https://accountscenter.facebook.com/personal_info).
After I change my facebook's email address and sign in,  I get a `attributes required: [email]` error.

Is this happening to others as well or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance